# Can i turn off all Firefox logging on Android, how?

Tags: logging, firefox-for-android

Just found 8 [gc- and cc- logs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Performance/GC_and_CC_logs) of about 100MB each on my phone. Not the first time I've had problems with Firefox creating unwanted log files. Is there a setting I can make to turn off all logging?
Seems weird to have any logging enabled by default, certainly logging that makes several text files of over 100MB on a phone app.

Comment: Where is the log directory that it is creating?

Comment: Not the original poster but: on my phone these are stored in Download/memory-reports/ and have names like cc-edges. <bunch of numbers>.log. There were other files with 'content' in their names but I just deleted 3GBytes of them so my phone would work.